# Random combinations from different arrays with not repetition

Tags: javascript, arrays, sorting, random, generator

Very new to the site and javascript so.
Been looking in the forum for a while but couldn't find the answer I was looking for, or at least couldn't understand the threads I'd read.

I'm tryng to make a generator to create as many combinations as needed of the arrays above without repeating the combination and using only one item of each array per iteration. There are also a few extra needs I'd add such as an unique id for the iteration and an extra property to mark the iterations where all the properties have the same value.

This is the code

```
var accesories = ["pijama" , "urban" , "joker" , "joyboy" , "crypto"];
var hats = accesories;
var tshirts = accesories;
var boots = accesories;


var cards = [];

function randomizeParts() {
model.accesories = accesories[Math.floor(Math.random() * 5)];
model.hats = hats[Math.floor(Math.random() * 5)];
model.tshirts = tshirts[Math.floor(Math.random() * 5)];
model.boots = boots[Math.floor(Math.random() * 5)];
};


function addInsomnio (quantity) {

for (let i = 1 ; i <= quantity ; i++){
    model = {
        id : 0,
        accesories: 0,
        hats: 0,
        tshirts: 0,
        boots: 0}

    //adding four digits id

    i < 10 ? model.id = '000' + i : i < 100 ? model.id = '00' + i : i < 1000 ? model.id = '0' + i : i <= 10000 ? model.id = i :false;

    //randomizing parts

    randomizeParts() 

    //checking if rarity was generated

   model.accesories === model.hats && model.accesories === model.tshirts && model.accesories === model.boots ? model.rarity = "original" : false;
    
    //checking its unique
    
   // ????

    //Pushing a beautifull brand new and unique card

    cards.push(model);
 }

};
```

is there a way to compare the random **model** to the existing objects in **cards** before pushing and so randomize it again as many times as needed if that combination already exist?

Note: this is planned to be used one time only to generate a 10,000 items json as a support for a photoshop script.

Comment: Is this the typical size (5) & number (4) of arrays? Or is the real case much larger in either size or number?

Comment: This is just a reduced version to try the script. The size will be near to 30 i think, but the numbers of arrays will always be 4.

Comment: Are you just trying to get the permutations of 5x5x5x5 in a random order? (ie 625 total results for an array of 5)

Comment: this might come in handy: http://phrogz.net/lazy-cartesian-product

Comment: @Jamiec yes, but not necessary all of the permutations.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can identify each combination with a unique number, and maintain a set of used numbers:

```js
function choices(count, ...arrays) {
    let used = new Set;
    let size = arrays.reduce((size, arr) => size * arr.length, 1);
    if (count > size) count = size;
    let result = [];
    for (let i = 0; i < count; i++) {
        let k;
        do {
            k = Math.floor(Math.random() * size);
        } while (used.has(k));
        used.add(k);
        result.push(arrays.reduce((acc, arr) => {
            acc.push(arr[k % arr.length]);
            k = Math.floor(k / arr.length);
            return acc;
        }, []));
    }
    return result;
}

let accesories = ["a", "b", "c", "d", "e"];
let hats = ["A", "B", "C", "D", "E"];
let tshirts = ["1", "2", "3", "4", "5"];
let boots = [".", ";", "?", "!"];

// Get 10 choices:
let result = choices(10, accesories, hats, tshirts, boots);
console.log(result);
```

Comment: Sorry if it's much to ask, but I dont understand some parts of the solution and also I don't want to copy and paste it without understanding it. Could you explain me what is /let used = new Set;/ and /used.add(k)/ ?

Comment: A `Set` is a data structure that stores unique elements, and allows for quick check whether it already contains a given value. Values are added to it with `add`. See [documentation of Set](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Set). Alternatively you can use a plain object instead of a `Set`, and use `used = {}` and `used[k] = 1` and `while (used[k])`.

Comment: Thank you very much! will study the documentation.